# How to get combobox list from a third party software?

Tags: combobox, autohotkey

There is a third party software and there is a combo box in that. I'd like to copy the combo box list. I believe AHK could do it but I can't use exact coordinates because the 3rd party software resize the window often. 
Is there a way to get information from the combo box (in AHK or in any other way) without knowing the exact coordinates of the combo box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible with AutoHotkey. You can use [ImageSearch](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/ImageSearch.htm) command for it. I recommend use `bmp` image format with it, it worked for me well, while I had some problem with `jpg`. I used [Paint.Net](http://www.getpaint.net/) for editing my images and they worked well.
Try to make image for search as unique as possible. Make screenshot not only of combobox but also some nearby area that does not changes, like this image:

[image: combobox]

In that way you get coordinates of upper left corner of your image. So you need to adjust coordinates you got from [ImageSearch](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/ImageSearch.htm) to get real coordinates of combobox. Just add or subtract necessary amount of pixels and you have real combobox coordinates.

*Also, always use AutoHotkey and its documenatation from http://ahkscript.org/ (current uptodate version, new official website)! AutoHotkey and its documentation from autohotkey.com is outdated and you may have some problems using them!*